# Update one column with information from two others?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with First_Name and Last_Name and want to update the Display_Name field with a combined First_Name + Last_Name.

Is this possible with mysql?

Comment: Is the Display_Name in the same table?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
update table_name set display_name = concat(first_name, ' ', last_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1 - Using GENERATED COLUMNS**

You can use **GENERATED COLUMNS** columns for that so you won't need to update the values every time the first and lastname changes coz MySQL will do it for you. Update your `display_name` by this query

```
ALTER TABLE yourtablename CHANGE display_name `display_name` VARCHAR(100) AS (CONCAT(first_name, ' ', first_name)) stored;
```

To Add a Generated Column just

```
ALTER TABLE yourtablename ADD COLUMN display_name VARCHAR(100) AS (CONCAT(first_name, ' ', first_name)) stored;
```

Check this link [Understanding Generated Columns](https://gabi.dev/2016/10/17/understanding-generated-columns/)

**SOLUTION 2 - UPDATE QUERY**

If you want to update manually use `CONCAT` in your update query without using GENERATED COLUMNS.

```
UPDATE yourtablename SET display_name=(CONCAT(first_name, ' ', first_name));
```